# @Inject not working in vue with typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, dependency-injection

Am trying to inject a service in vue as follows.

in more-information.component.ts

```
@Inject('moreInformationService') private moreInformationService: () => MoreInformationService;
```

in more-information.service.ts

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { Store } from 'vuex';
export default class MoreInformationService {
  constructor(private $store: Store<any>) {
  }    
}
```

But am getting the following Waring in console and its not working as expected

```
webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.esm.js:629 [Vue warn]: Injection "moreInformationService" not found

found in

---> <MoreInformation> at src/main/webapp/app/MSB/products/more-information/more-information.vue
       <BlankLayout> at src/main/webapp/app/MSB/layouts/BlankLayout.vue
         <App> at src/main/webapp/app/app.vue
           <Root>
```

Comment: What's `@Inject`? Is it from vue-property-decorator? The error means that the dependency wasn't registered, with `provide` or else. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , not just separate snippets.

Comment: sorry its my mistake i forgot to register dependency using Provide. but ho register the class.

Comment: it can be fixed by this
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: { App },
  template: '<App/>',
  router,
  provide: {
    moreInformationService: () => new MoreInformationService()
}
});

any other better way to solve this ?

Comment: That's how I'd expect it to be solved. Consider posting it, self-answers are welcome on SO.

Answer (score 2):

I forgot to register the service using `provide`

The following changes fixed my issue,

```
import MoreInformationService from '@/products/more-information/more-information.service';

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: { App },
  template: '<App/>',
  router,
  provide: {
    moreInformationService: () => new MoreInformationService(store)
  },
  store
});
```

if there any better option please answer.